# How to filter rows based on splitting a text column and showing other rows that have share at least one chunk?

Tags: google-bigquery

| item | tags |
| --- | --- |
| shirt | tag, tag1, tag2, tag3 |
| coat | tag, tag7, tag8 |
| shoes | tag1, tag2, tag5 |
| jacket | tag4, tag5 |

I need to iterate on each row and select rows that share at least one of these tags.

For example, on "shirt", I need to filter on rows that have tag, or tag1, or tag2, or tag3. "coat" and "shoes" are the result I want.

If I take "coat", only "shirt" will be returned. It does not matter if "coat" is also returned.

How can I do that in a efficient way ?

Currently my "tags" column uses a string type, but I'm open to use a different type / structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `split()` to split string into rows  :

```
select *
from mytable c
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(tags,',')) AS tag_id
where tag_id = 'tag' or tag_id = 'tag1' or  tag_id = 'tag2' or tag_id = 'tag3'
```

To filter by a specific item instead of tags then :

```
select distinct s.item
from mytable t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(tags)) tag_id
INNER JOIN (
  select *
  from mytable t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(tags)) AS tag
) AS s on s.tag = tag_id
where t.item = 'shirt'
```

Comment: This solution works when the chosen item is "shirt", but does not generalize on the chosen item, if it gets different to coat, or any other. Are you sure about this solution? @thomascer

Comment: It will work. But it would be more efficient to iterate based on the item as you suggested. I'm currently setting my tags as an array to try your solution.

Comment: good point @lemon, I misunderstand the question, I have updated my answer to filter by item

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use arrays for your tags, you can approach this problem with the following steps:

- filter tags from the table according to your item value
- unnest tags relative to your filtered array
- search which items have at least one coat tag, using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT item 
FROM tab t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM       tab t2 
              CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t2.tags) AS tag
              WHERE t2.item = <your_chosen_item>
                AND tag IN t1.tags)
```